# phpwhois not working on godaddy

Tags: php

I installed This script [PHPwhois](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/) on my shared hosting server from go-daddy. I's not getting the Whois information. On my localhost This working is working without any problem.

Here is my script

```
<?php

include_once('whois/whois.main.php');

    $whois = new Whois();
    $allowproxy = false;
    $whois->non_icann = true;
    $result = $whois->Lookup("facebook.com"); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);  
echo "</pre>";  


?>
```

Comment: It probably has to do with a firewall or permissions.  Possibly both.  I doubt you'll be able to do that from GoDaddy shared hosting.

Comment: @crontab but how ? should i open a support ticket ?

Comment: You can try, but I doubt they'll do anything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing external connections from godaddy servers you can only use ports 80 (http) or 443 (https). If you have specified any other ports it will be blocked.

See here, http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/287/do-you-support-fsockopen

Comment: I opened a support ticket on godaddy , they replied same